# Cannot read property 'index Of' of undefined in HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I try to highlight on my page the search expression with a button. 
Can anyone help me please to solve this problem?

> Uncaught 
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined at highlight (?q=Python:11) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (?q=Python:24)

The JS code:

```
function highlight(text) {
        var titles = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
        for (var x in titles) {
            var innerHTML = titles[x].innerHTML;
            var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
            if (index >= 0) {
                innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index, index + text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
                x.innerHTML = innerHTML;
            }
        }
    }
```

Line 11:

```
var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
```

Line 24:

```
<button onclick="highlight('{{ search_expression }}')">Highlight search expression</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: @NineBerry well that's the correct answer, but the question is not the same I think :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `for .. in` to iterate over the list of elements, but a traditional `for` loop.

```
function highlight(text) 
{
        var titles = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
        for (var i=0; i < titles.length; i++) 
        {
            var title = titles[i];
            var innerHTML = title.innerHTML;

            // Work with title some more.
        }
}
```

For an explanation what is happening see [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: I'd just like to add you could replace `for .. in` with `for .. of`, which is for looping enumerables. Differently from `for .. in`, with `for (let x of yourArray)` in each loop `x` would be assigned a value in the array - but I'd reccomend looping through indexes, it's more explicit and you're sure about what is happening.

Comment: `for .. of` is not supported in Internet Explorer, so not an alternative if you cannot control what browsers are used. One could use `foreach()` on the collection instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, working with the help of the other answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` might be `undefined`. You have to check if `innerHTML` is defined before calling `innerHTML.indexOf`

```
var innerHTML = titles[x].innerHTML
if (innerHTML) {
  var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text)
  ...
}
```